# How can I access the Hacker News API using the Firebase SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hacker-news-api

The Hacker News API documentation says:

> If you can use one of the many [Firebase client libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries/), you really should. The libraries handle networking efficiently and can raise events when things change. Be sure to check them out.

It doesn't specify *how* to do that though. How can I use the Firebase client libraries to interact with the Hacker News API, to gain more efficient networking and support for listening for events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interact it with it using the [Realtime Database API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). Set the `databaseURL` to `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com`, and you can make queries using the Firebase client libraries. The paths are the same as the paths in the API, without the `.json` file extension. For example, this would get data for the user `jl` using the web client:

```js
var config = {
    databaseURL: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database = firebase.database();
console.log((await database.ref("v0/user/jl").get()).val());
```

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76477190/how-to-use-hacker-news-firebase-realtime-api-using-the-firebase-sdk. Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong?