# Do I need to use Firebase to access all Hacker News articles?

Tags: java, firebase, get, hacker-news-api

I have my Java server setup with all the appropriate packages (API, [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object), model, service, etc.). On the [Hacker News](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_News) (HN) website they explain that I should use Firebase to call their API.

Do I need to configure Firebase to access all the HN articles from the API, even though I have access to Java's built-in API call functionalities?

I can retrieve one article and see the JSON data in [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info):

```java
URL getUrl = new URL("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/29042728.json?print=pretty");
print = pretty
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) getUrl.openConnection();

// If a connection (200 OK) is made, data is buffered
BufferedReader art = new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer jsonResponseData = new StringBuffer();
String readLine = null;

// Appends data from the response line by line
while ((readLine = art.readLine()) != null) {
    jsonResponseData.append(readLine);
}

in.close();
```

Is Firebase still needed for something else?

Reference: *[Hacker News API](https://github.com/HackerNews/API)*

Comment: Here's the hackernews website: https://news.ycombinator.com/

Comment: This is [being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416125/need-help-improving-my-question-to-remove-the-question-ban)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the Firebase SDK to interact with the API, although [you *can* if you want to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69518903/14004262). Using the Firebase SDK gets you minor performance gains, at the cost of some more implementation complexity. But you can also just make requests to the API endpoints using a normal HTTP client using the API endpoints listed in the documentation (like `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json`).

Comment: You are correct. I decided to just make the requests using the Java URL class and writing the logic to make get requests to a range of articles. Thank you!